# Как в django привязать друг к другу два разных запроса

Tags: python, django, telegram-bot, oauth, битрикс24

Имеется две таблицы пользователей (связаны ManyToMany): одна телеграмм бота, вторая  битрикс24. Работа с телеграмм ведется через запросы POST (прием сообщений), авторизация OAuth2 битрикса приходит через GET запрос. Проблема в том что не могу связать телеграмм пользователя, т.е. не знаю от кого пришла авторизация битрикс. Может не очень понятно объяснил, может подскажете в каком направление копать? С сессиями пробовал, что то не получилось, и сессии вроде как разные , в телеграмм свой клиент, а авторизация идет через браузер.

Comment: Почему many to many? У одного бота может быть много битриксных юзеров?

Comment: Да почему бы и нет, например я сам захожу под администратором битрикса, и потом для теста под другим пользователем. И так же наоборот могу заходить с разных учетных записей телеграмма